# how to send a http put request to the server?

Tags: http, put

i don't know anything about how to send HTTP put request but i really needed to do this please help me

here is the format :

```
PUT / HTTP/1.1
Host: hey.domain.com
Content-type: application/j son
Content-Length: LENGTH
X-name of key-Key: e97d6b85fc85568a63bcfce872caeee028ea5b61
{
"name": "Bruce Wayne",
"email": "bruce@gothamcity.com",
"phone": "+919999888899",
"experienced": false,
"profile": "python"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use curl

```
curl -XPUT -d '{"name": "Bruce Wayne", "email": "bruce@gothamcity.com", "phone": \
    "+919999888899", "experienced": false, "profile": "python" }' \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://hey.domain.com
```

Comment: open up a terminal and type in the above command, there is no video - it is really, really simple

Comment: i was trying it in windows actually really don't know about it anything.

Comment: Ah ok, well glad that you figured it out